# VS 2008 vs VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Guys would you say that having installed VS 2008 and VS 2010 on one machine would the latter work slower than the former? Because when I work with VS 2010 I can't get the feeling of that it is slower than the VS 2008.

Comment: Good thing you don't remember VS6 then.

Comment: @Idigas unfortunately I started my adventure with C++ just two years ago

Comment: Maybe you could give some of your PC's specs?  CPU, RAM, etc?  Also, what kind of projects/solutions are you opening up to see this slowness?  Or are you talking about just the initial start of VS2010?

Comment: @sunpech my comp CPU and RAM are really irrelevant here. What would you do if I would give them to you. Would you build the same and do the test? Either it is visible on your machine like for example IntelliSense response or not. I can see it clearly and when I work with VS 2008 it is much more faster than VS 2010.

Comment: They're relevant because if your system is say 5+ years old, then yes, vs2010 will probably run slower.  I have a system that's almost 4 years old, with 4GB of RAM, and Win7 64 Ult, and I run both vs2008 and vs2010 just fine.  My web and WPF apps also run similarly.  If you would like help on your issue(s), please provide as much relevant information as you can.  For instance, you just now provided info on Intellisense repsonse.

Comment: Yes VS2010 **IS** slower. Its really noticeable in a virtual machine (when coding under Linux, using VMWare). If your PC won't run it, you should upgrade it or use VS2008. (Or sharpdevelop/netbeans, don't know what you code there.)

Comment: @Shiki, that's a good response; you should post it as an answer to the question, not just a comment.

Comment: Added it as an answer and added +1 to the question. Don't see a reason for -1.

Comment: The question as it stands is argumentative.  I don't see how you can honestly answer it without starting out with, "It depends...".  Not enough context has been given without an answer making big assumptions about what the question could imply.

Comment: @atch - Why the attitude ? People are trying to help you, or at least give sensible advice, yet you don't want to provide them with the info they're asking. By definition, if you're asking a question, goes, that you don't know enough about the problem to be making your own conclusions. Otherwise, you wouldn't be asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes VS2010 IS (clearly) slower. Its really noticeable in a virtual machine (when coding under Linux, using VMWare). If your PC won't run it, you should upgrade it (cpu is the key word here) or use VS2008.

(Or replace your development tool with an alternative IDE. For example Netbeans for cpp, (or qtcreator), sharpdevelop for C#...don't know what you code there.. but guess the alternative would be a new question already.)

Comment: Running any large application in a virtual machine will clearly be slower don't you think?  My MBP running Win7 Ult 64 in Parallels is clearly slower than if I ran it natively.

Comment: But I used both VS2008 and VS2010 for development. And the slower reaction is clearly noticeable. (Even on my developer machine). Guess one have to pay for the new features.

Comment: @Shiki thanks for your answer. I'm affraid that as things are for the moment everyone (majority anyway) works with VS so it wouldn't be wise to change enviroment. And as for NetBeans - I really can't stand this IDE and also I'm more than certain that NetBeans it's even slower than VS 2010. They written in Java and I'm affraid everyting written in Java is slow.

Comment: @Shiki And I'd rather be dead than code C++ in IDE written in Java

Comment: Geany, Code::Blocks ?

Comment: n o t e p a d++??

Comment: @bobobo: Pfeh. notepad.exe .. what else one would need? ;D